# recursive function in c for the furmula: a(n)=a(n-1)+a(n-2)

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci, function-definition

I am trying to write a recursive function for the formula:
a(n)=a(n-1)+a(n-2)
I've tried to simply write it out:

```
 unsigned int ladder(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int ret=0;
    if (n < 1)
        return ret;
    ret = ladder(n - 1) + ladder(n - 2);


}
```

but it goes into stack overflow when calling for ladder(n-2)
(for some reason it sets n as a very large integer)

I feel like I'm missing something very basic but can't figure out what.

Comment: `ladder(1 - 2)` does something *unexpected* :)

Comment: @wtz ... `ladder(1 - 2)` avaluates to `ladder(UINT_MAX)` (something like `ladder(18446744073709551615)`)

Comment: It might not be expected but *(for some reason it sets n as a very large integer)* is well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns nothing in case when n is not less than 1.

Also when n is equal to 1 then the expression n - 2 yields the maximum value that can be stored in object of the type unsigned int.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
unsigned long long int ladder( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? n : ladder( n - 1 ) + ladder( n - 2 );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int ladder( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? n : ladder( n - 1 ) + ladder( n - 2 );
}

int main( void )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%llu ", ladder( i ) );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368
```